# PHPExcel download file in browser broken

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to use the library PHPexcel to download a .xlsx file in the browser but the downloaded file seem broken

[image]

```
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);

            $filenames = explode('/',$filename);

            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filenames[(count($filenames)-1)].'"');
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
            exit;
```

If I open the file saved on the server, everything is fine.
Do I have the wrong content-type in my header?

Comment: phpExcel is dead, [Long Live `phpSpreadsheet`](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Although that looks like a UTF-8 issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can't use it. My company is using PHP 7.0. The file generated on the server with PHPExcel is fine. It's just when I try to download it with the browser that I get this encoding issue

Answer (score 0):

The four blank rows at the top suggest you are exporting other characters before the Excel file, and thus creating an invalid file. Check your script to ensure the opening PHP marker is at the top of the file, (no empty lines above) and there are no echo statements before the Excel file output.